# Create TreeStore for TreePanel with ExtJS4

Tags: javascript, tree, extjs4.2

I am facing a problem trying to create a TreeGrid, I receive a complex JSON which I need to process by extracting data using "for" and conditionals since I have to form the array of components for the tree.

This is the current component working oin a Java UI with swing:

[image]

In ExtJS, I expect something like this:

[image]

And this is a sample of the array I formed to obtain that structure for EXTJS TreeGrid:

[image]

I've created a more simple structure on JSFiddle:

```
var statuses = [];
var dispatchesA = [];
var dispatchesB = [];
var rootFolders = [];
var s1 = {name: 'Sent', id: '1'};
var s2 = {name: 'Complete', id: '2'};
var s3 = {name: 'Pending', id: '3'};
var s4 = {name: 'Process', id: '4'};
statuses.push(s1);              
statuses.push(s2);
statuses.push(s3);
statuses.push(s4);

var dispatch1 = {afterhours: true, dispatchId: '001', 
                     status: 'Complete', statList: statuses};
var dispatch2 = {afterhours: true, dispatchId: '002', 
                     status: 'Complete', statList: statuses}; 

var dispatch3 = {afterhours: false, dispatchId: '001', 
                     status: 'Complete', statList: statuses};

dispatchesA.push(dispatch1);
dispatchesA.push(dispatch2);    
dispatchesB.push(dispatch3);

var rootElement1 = {nodeDisplay: 'WKGROUP1', children: dispatchesA};
var rootElement2 = {nodeDisplay: 'WKGROUP2', children: dispatchesB};
rootFolders.push(rootElement1);
rootFolders.push(rootElement2);
```

I want to create a TreeStore based on a similar Structure, so far, this is my code for the ExtJS side:

```
createTreeStore: function(target) {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {            
            autoLoad: false,
            clearOnLoad: false,
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: rootFolders
            }
        });
    },
```

I wonder how to achieve that I made an approach but not working at all, since the TreeGrid is showed but not the data.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work on this in the traditional way. I solved the problem by retrieving the base json object and iterate over the data to create my own custom objects that would be used by tree store. It worked as desired. Was kind of tedious to iterate the object, but, for sure, for the business requirements of my job, was necessary, there was no other way.

If in case somebody have same problem and needs specific structure for a tree and the json data incoming from server does not adapt, I will strongly suggest to iterate the json object and retrieve the data required in order to create custom objects to be used and inserted into the store.

Regards.